# Running different kernels (e.g. Python 2.7) on Juypter

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter

I have `Python 2.7.10` (which I just installed) and I recently installed `Jupyter`. However the only kind of notebook I can create when I open `Jupyter` is `iTorch` and `Python 3`.

How can I create a notebook in `Python 2.7`?

I'm attempting to complete a TensorFlow tutorial and that is written in `Python 2.7.`

Comment: How did you install Python 2.7? If you're using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), then things are going to be easy. Related: what does this give you? `python -V`?

Comment: hey @kwinkunks it gives me ' Python 2.7.10 ' . I downloaded python from the python homepage.

Comment: Try this: `ipython2 kernelspec install-self --user` then see if you have Python 2 kernels in the notebook. That should get you going; I will write a quick answer on a better strategy though.

Comment: :-/ it came up with an error `ImportError: No module named jupyter_client.kernelspecapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run multiple versions of Python is with *virtual environments*. Then you can run whatever version you like whenever you like. A great way to do this for people who don't want to spend a lot of time working on it (like me) is with Continuum's Anaconda distribution of Python. I couldn't get the hang of virtual environments till this came along.

Before going any further, I recommend uninstalling the Python 2.7 you installed, and reverting to your system's Python as far as possible.

Then install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Install the Python 3.5 version since you'll want to use that most of the time. Almost all libraries I use support it now. Google App Engine and TensorFlow are the only things I use that don't.

Now you should be able to create a Python 2.7 environment like so:

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

The `python2` is just the name; call it whatever you like. The `anaconda` bit installs the scientific Python stack; you can leave that off if you want a very basic environment.

Creating the environment doesn't start it. Start the environment with:

```
source activate python2
```

Add it to the notebook with:

```
ipython kernelspec install-self --user
```

Now install TensorFlow using [whichever command Google recommends](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#download-and-setup) for your system.

Whenever you want to use that environment, do the `source activate` command again. To leave it, start another environment or type `source deactivate`. You can make as many environments as you like, with whatever versions of Python and whatever other packages you want.

[Read more](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) about managing environments.